# What should I to this code to check leap years after 1900

Tags: python-3.x

```
***def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if(( year % 400 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 ) or ( year % 4 ==0 )):
        leap = True
    # Write your logc here

    return leap
year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))***
```

I use this code to find leap years after 1900 for the hacker rank python 'write a function' exercise but it shows wrong for the year 2100. what should I do ???

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
( year % 400 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 ) or ( year % 4 ==0 )
```

is wrong. Change your code such that

1. `year % 400 == 0` leap year
2. `year % 100 == 0` not a leap year
3. `year % 4 == 0` leap year
4. all other: not a leap year

You could also use this algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm